# create a file in Virtual Memory

Tags: c#, sharepoint, filestream

Hi i am trying to upload a local into Sharepoint documentLibrary.

The following code works well to upload a file into document Libray.

```
    public void UploadFile(string srcUrl, string destUrl)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(srcUrl))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} does not exist",
                srcUrl), "srcUrl");
        }

        SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl).OpenWeb();

        FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(srcUrl);
        byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
        fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
        fStream.Close();

        site.Files.Add(destUrl, contents);
    }
```

But i need to create a text file in document Library which contains a content like "This is a new file" without saving it in local disk.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) instead of `FileStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the string into a byte array and create the file from that array.

As an aside, note that your code leaks an `SPSite` and an `SPWeb`, which is quite dangerous since those objects can take a lot of memory. You need to properly dispose of them, e.g. with nested [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statements:

```
using System.Text;

public void AddNewFile(string destUrl)
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(destUrl)) {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(
                "This is a new file.");
            web.Files.Add(destUrl, bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
public void UploadText(string text, Encoding encoding, string destUrl)
{
    SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl).OpenWeb();
    site.Files.Add(destUrl, encoding.GetBytes(text));
}
```

PS: you will need an encoding to convert from a string to an array of bytes. You can hardcode one or pass it as a parameter just like I did.